# How to solve sql statement in VB.net using ms access

Tags: vb.net

```
     If InvoiceNumberTextBox.Text <> "" And ClientNoTextBox.Text <> "" And FirstNameTextBox.Text <> "" And LastNameTextBox.Text <> "" And ProductNameTextBox.Text <> "" And ProductCodeTextBox.Text <> "" And ProductUnitTextBox.Text <> "" And QuantityTextBox.Text <> "" And ProductPriceTextBox.Text <> "" And TotalPriceTextBox.Text <> "" And Label1.Text <> "" And DateToDeliverDateTimePicker.Text <> "" And AddressTextBox.Text <> "" And ContactNoTextBox.Text <> "" Then
        Dim DT As String
        DT = Label1.Text
        cmdinsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Orders ([InvoiceNumber], [ClientNo], [FirstName], [LastName], [ProductName], [ProductCode], [Unit], [Quantity], [Price], [TotalPrice], [DateToday], [DateToDeliver], [Address], [ContactNo]) VALUES ('" & InvoiceNumberTextBox.Text & "', '" & ClientNoTextBox.Text & "', '" & FirstNameTextBox.Text & "', '" & LastNameTextBox.Text & "', '" & ProductNameTextBox.Text & "', '" & ProductCodeTextBox.Text & "', '" & ProductUnitTextBox.Text & "', '" & QuantityTextBox.Text & "', '" & ProductPriceTextBox.Text & "', '" & TotalPriceTextBox.Text & "', '" & Label1.Text & "', '" & DateToDeliverDateTimePicker.Text & "', '" & AddressTextBox.Text & "', '" & ContactNoTextBox.Text & "')"
        cmdinsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmdinsert.Connection = cnn
        cmdinsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Added")
        ProductNameTextBox.Clear()
        ProductPriceTextBox.Clear()
        FirstNameTextBox.Clear()
        ContactNoTextBox.Clear()
        TotalPriceTextBox.Clear()
        ProductUnitTextBox.Clear()
        LastNameTextBox.Clear()
        AddressTextBox.Clear()
        ClientNoTextBox.Clear()
        ProductCodeTextBox.Clear()
        QuantityTextBox.Clear()
        InvoiceNumberTextBox.Clear()
        If QuantityTextBox.Text <> "" Then
            cmdupdate.CommandText = "update Products set Quantity = '" & Label4.Text & "' where ProductCode = '" & ProductCodeTextBox.Text & "'"
            cmdupdate.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Connection = cnn
            cmdupdate.ExecuteNonQuery()


        Else
            MsgBox("PLEASE CHECK YOUR FORM")

        End If
        cmdupdate.Dispose()
        Me.ProductsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DatabaseCasanovaDataSet.Products)
        ProductsDataGridView.Refresh()
        ProductsDataGridView.Update()
    End If
        cmdinsert.Dispose()
```

Debug say is Mismatch expression but i check 3x on my database order by in orders table
Anyone to check this if im wrong?

The Label1.text is a Date

Orders table list correctly

InvoiceNumber
ClientNo
FirstName
LastName
ProductName
ProductCode
Unit
Quantity
Price
TotalPrice
DateToday
DateToDeliver
Address
ContactNo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing 14 strings to your table. If any of your field in the table is not of type Text you risk the Data Type Mismatch. Really you should change your code to use a parameterized query and for each parameter pass the correct datatype.

For example, if the DateToday fields wants a datetime, you pass a datetime, not a string

```
cmdinsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Orders ([InvoiceNumber], [ClientNo], [FirstName], " & _
"[LastName], [ProductName], [ProductCode], [Unit], [Quantity], [Price], [TotalPrice], " & _
"[DateToday], [DateToDeliver], [Address], [ContactNo]) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", InvoiceNumberTextBox.Text)
......
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p11", Convert.ToDateTime(Label1.Text))
.....
cmdinsert.Connection = cnn
cmdinsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

In the example above the 11th parameter correspond to the DateToday field. As you can see, I have forced it to be a datetime thus the correct value is passed to the database. The same thing should be done for numerics (integer/decimal) but also for strings because a parameter avoids the problem of single quotes in textbox values.

Comment: in the values is always ?.
on paramaters on with that? what is @p1?

Comment: Yes, you leave the `?` unchanged, and add the parameters in the right order. Their names (like `@p1`) are virtually irrelevant and can be used just to keep the orientation up.

Comment: Always miss datamatch :(

Comment: Sorry to be late to answer your comment. Did you solve the type mismatch?

Comment: As explained by @KekuSemau in OleDb parameters are not recognized by their name, but only by their position in the parameters collection. You specify the position of a parameter inserting a ? as placeholder. Then in the same exact order you add the parameters to the command collection. Of course the collection wants every element to be named and thus I have given a simple progressive name to the elements in the collection